# Image of an integer polynomial in the integers mod 7

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

Given p(x,y) = x<sup>2</sup> - 7y<sup>2</sup> - 24 ∈ ℤ[x,y], does the image in ℤ<sub>7</sub>[x,y] become x<sup>2</sup> - 3 or x<sup>2</sup> + 4? Or could I use either to determine whether or not p(x,y) has any solutions in ℤ[x,y]?

Comment: Either will do, they are equivalent $\pmod 7$.

Comment: Indeed, @lulu, I would have said that as polynomials over the field with seven elements, they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

You could use either $x^2-3$ or $x^2+4$, or in fact $x^2+(4+n)\times 7$ for any $ n \in \mathbb N;$

adding any multiple of $7$ doesn't change things modulo $7$.